# Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Tags: php, session

my class.inc file:

```
<?php
class logout{
    public function logout(){
        $_SESSION = array();
        if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params["httponly"]);
        }
        session_destroy();
    }   
}

?>
```

used code for my logout:

```
session_start();
require($path."include/class.inc");
if(!empty($_GET['logout'])){
    $object=new logout();
    $object->logout();
    $content='5;url='.$path.'index.php';
}
```

When the `logout` function is called, it destroys the session, but shows the warning:

```
Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in class.inc on line 9
```

I am unable to troubleshoot, as the session is not being destroyed by any other means before the `session_destroy()` of `class.inc`.

Comment: Where are you starting the session?

Comment: This error warning comes when there is not any session started.

Comment: i'm starting the session in each page at the top just after `<?php` with `session_start();`

Comment: Also at your logout page?

Comment: @TobiasKun my logout is on same page only. it's inside a head.inc file which is included in every page.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to call the function mentioned below at the top your logout function in the logout class.

```
session_start();
```

Add the above function and try it out. If you don’t start the session at the top of your file, it will throw exceptions like “headers already sent”, “can’t start the session”, etc.

Comment: though i'm including the class file in a page where the session already started... i've to use `session_start()` in every class the session is being used. else it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 15):

This error is common when you haven't started the session beforehand

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_start();
  }
```

Comment: @Jonathan you may try `if(!session_id()) session_start();`

Answer (score 6):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
        session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the `session_destroy()` error message when I started using `session_write_close()`.  To determine if `session_destroy()` should be called or not, I had to do the following:

```
class Session {
    public static function start() {
        self::$haveSession = true;
        session_start();
    }
    public static function finish() {
        session_write_close();
        self::$haveSession = false;
    }
    public static function clear() {
        if (self::$haveSession) {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

In PHP >= 5.4 it should work to replace `if (self::$haveSession)` with `if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code to start a session if it didn't start before

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your session  
    `session_start();` and you can destroy your session

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    class logout{
        public function logout(){
            $_SESSION = array();
            if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
                $params = session_get_cookie_params();
                setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params["httponly"]);
            }
            session_destroy();
        }   
    }

?>
```

Comment: remove `@` from `@session_destroy();` it'll show the warning.

Comment: it's not correct man. it's showing another notice
`Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in class.inc on line 2` as the file is included in each file after `session_start();`. so two `session_start();` will show a notice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call session_start() before you call session_destroy();

Are you storing session in data in files or in a database. If you are storing it in a database, I normally just delete the record from the session table that corresponds to the session id, that way you don't have to unregister each session var and it actually deletes the whole session.